# Meaning of "au" in "Nous allons le chercher au train."

Tags: vocabulaire

What does the *au* in the following example signify?

> 8:20 Arrivée des élèves. Nous allons les chercher au train.

Does that mean that we are picking up the pupils "by train" (i.e. we are using the train to bring them here, e.g. from the airport), or that we are going to pick them up "at the train" when they arrive by train?

Comment: *By train* would have been ***en** train*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"au" is the contraction of "à le" (at the).
So it means "at the train"

"à la gare" (at the station) would be more elegant.

Comment: More elegant but less precise, especially if the station is large. *Au train* means you pick the pupils directly on the platform while *à la gare* might just mean you wait at a meeting point or even outside the station.

Comment: @jlliagre *aller chercher au train* can still be quite vague on wether you're picking up the person on the platform or just at the station (at least in my understanding).

Comment: @XouDo *Aller chercher au train* is a rare compared to *chercher à la gare* (between 20 and 30 times more rare according to Google Books) so in my opinion, when you use it, you want to pass an extra piece of information. This is even more true when talking about pupils. In any case, while *au train* might still be quite vague in some cases, it is nevertheless more precise than *à la gare*.